# How to group together boxes of different traces for subplots in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

In the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/) about plotly boxes we are told that for Group Box plots we use `boxmode` so that to group together boxes for each value x

```
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_title='normalized moisture',
    boxmode='group' # group together boxes of the different traces for each value of x
)
```

My question is how do you apply this in case you are using *Box subplots*?
An example would be nice.

In my case I have 5 box subplots and I have put `boxmode` in the layout but this affects *all* subplots, even the ones that have only one trace for each value of x, which gives a weird appearance to the plot.

Related to this, if you have 5 box subplots with *only one trace* for x value, the `boxmode` option affects the plots anyway

Answer (score 3):

- extending https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#grouped-box-plots example to do sub plots
- this does work, however it does offset x-axis in subplots (either as rows or columns)
- have tried setting various **xaxis** layout parameters to prevent offsetting without success
- is this the behaviour you are noting does not work well in sub-plots?

```py
import itertools
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

x = ['day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1',
     'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2']

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3)
for r,n in itertools.product(range(3), ["kale","carrots","radishes"]):
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=[f"{xx}.{r}" for xx in x], y=np.random.uniform(0,1, len(x)), name=f"{n}-{r}"), row=1, col=r+1)
    
fig.update_layout(boxmode="group")
fig.show()

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)
for r,n in itertools.product(range(3), ["kale","carrots","radishes"]):
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=[f"{xx}.{r}" for xx in x], y=np.random.uniform(0,1, len(x)), name=f"{n}-{r}"), row=r+1, col=1)
    
fig.update_layout(boxmode="group")
```

[image]